# Ubuntu and Samsung printer, printing strange code

Tags: printing, 17.04, samsung

I have a strange problem with all Samsung printers with Wi-Fi connection. When I try print some docs, pdf etc., printer prints some strange code.

[image]

I have installed Samsung driver.Is someone else having this problem?

Ubuntu 17.04, Dell XPS 13 9360

Comment: What happens when you print images? Are there any things that print correctly?

Comment: And what if you print a file with a few lines of text (like made with gedit or vi), not using  non-plain text files like Office files or pdf files. The files you describe are not plain ascii text. They have non-printing control characters in them and it looks like your driver/printer are treating them as ascii text and so you get what you see.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with my  Samsung printer (Xpress C460w).
The following solved for me:

I went to printers -> additional printer settings-> add
new window opens: go to network printer wait for a few seconds until your printer will be found, and click on it. On the right bottom as connection chose:

LPD network printer via DNS-SD

[image: New printer]

(for me Appsocket/HP Jetdirect also worked only the "Driverless IP" one made that code by printing)

Click on forward, wait a sec until the driver will be added, and print the test page to see if it worked

Comment: FYI, also this solution also works for Samsung C480FW with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (and Linux drivers are available here https://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-c480fw-driver/ )

Answer (score 0):

Using the original Samsung's driver helped me. I couldn't force my Elementary OS to use the right PPD file so I replaced the file in /etc/cups/ppds directly and restarted CUPS daemon.

```
cp uld/noarch/share/ppd/Samsung_C48x_Series.ppd ppd/Samsung_C48x_Series_on_192.168.1.100.ppd
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

It's not flawless, I can't print something like 10 MB photo, but still better than a pile of paper covered by nonsense.